# How to automate functional testing for background service that act as a system monitor? Such as linux daemon or windows service

Tags: windows, testing, service, daemon

I can't seems to find any good articles or guidelines on how to do automated testing for a background process that act as a system monitor, ie, part of the input is the system events or how the system is configured/comprised of, such as the number of users, user logins, file monitoring etc.

Anyone has some experience in this domain? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All testing is "inputs" and "output".  Your testing should start with a list of "inputs" and "outputs".  The actual test cases will be to create input data (log in user, log out user, etc) and then look for the expected output.  Verifying output may mean reading log files, querying the database used by the system monitor, etc.  It's hard to give more advice than this without knowing your product better.

You may need to speak with the developers to get a list of inputs and outputs.  They may need to create "testing hooks" so that you can create inputs/verify outputs.